# THREE.js Changing Textures On Load

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

We're loading in objects created in Blender, that we would like to change the texture without having to change the .mtl file that is being referenced when we load the object.

```
//load in all pieces
var board = this;
var loadComplete = 0;
this.loader.load('myobj1.obj', 'myobj1.mtl', function (object){
    board.obj2 = object;
    board.loader.load('myobj2.obj', 'myobj2.mtl', function(object){
        board.obj2 = object;
        board.obj2.material = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'Models/textures/blackmarble1.jpg' );
        board.loader.load('myobj3.obj', 'myobj3.mtl', function(object){
            board.obj3 = object;
    });
 });
});
```

so in this card, we're trying to change the obj2's texture. However, it just loads whatever is in the mtl. Which we want in certain scenarios, but not in others.

Also trying these methods do not do anything:

```
var blackTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Models/textures/blackmarble1.jpg');
obj2.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: blackTex});


obj2.material.uniforms.texture = blackTex;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The loader childs the meshes.

```
piece.children[0].children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: blackTex});
```